# Do all CPUs which support AVX2 also support SSE4.2 and AVX?

Tags: sse, simd, avx, avx2

I am planning to implement runtime detection of SIMD extensions. Is it such that if I find out that the processor has AVX2 support, it is also guaranteed to have SSE4.2 and AVX support?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Support for a more-recent Intel SIMD ISA extension implies support for previous SIMD ones.**

AVX2 definitely implies AVX1.

I think AVX1 implies all of SSE / SSE2 / SSE3 / SSSE3 / SSE4.1 / SSE4.2 feature bits must also be set in CPUID.  If not formally guaranteed, *many* things make this assumption and a CPU that violated it would probably not be commercially viable for general use.

Note that `popcnt` has its own feature bit, so in theory, you could have a CPU with AVX2 and SSE4.2, but not `popcnt`, but many things treat SSE4.2 as implying `popcnt`.  So it's more like you can advertise support for `popcnt` without SSE4.2.

---

In theory, you could make a CPU (or virtual machine) with AVX but which didn't accept the non-VEX legacy-SSE encoding of SSE4.2 instructions like `pcmpistri`, but I think you'd be violating Intel's guarantees about what the AVX feature bit implies.  Not sure if that's formally written down in a manual, but most software will assume that.  (SSE1 and SSE2 are baseline for x86-64, but not for 32-bit mode.)

But AVX1 *does* imply support for the VEX encoding of *all* SSE4.2 and earlier SIMD instructions, e.g. [`vpcmpistri`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PCMPISTRI.html) or [`vminss`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MINSS.html)

**`gcc -mavx2` definitely implies AVX1 and previous extensions**, (`-Q --help=target` to see) but will only emit code that uses the VEX encoding.  It will define the `__SSE4_2__` macro and so on, though, so GCC does treat AVX2 as implying earlier SSE extensions and `popcnt`, but not FMA, AES-NI, or PCLMUL.  Those are separate features even for GCC.

(In practice you should use `gcc -march=native` or `gcc -march=znver1` or whatever to enable all the features your CPU has, *and* set tuning options for it.  Not just `-mavx2 -mfma`, that leaves tuning settings at bad defaults like splitting every possibly-unaligned 256-bit load/store into 128-bit halves.  Or with recent GCC/clang, `-march=x86-64-v3` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Microarchitecture_levels) which leaves `-mtune=generic`, but these days that's appropriate for AVX2 CPUs: it's been a decade since Haswell.)

(Note that MSVC doesn't have as many SIMD ISA detection macros; it has one for AVX but not for all of the earlier SSE* extensions.  MSVC's model is designed around the assumption that programs will do runtime CPU detection instead of being compiled for the local machine.  Although MSVC does now have `-arch:AVX`, and `-arch:AVX2`, and `-arch:AVX512` options to use those as baselines.)

---

Note that AVX512 kind of breaks the traditions.  AVX512F implies support for AVX2 and everything before it, but beyond that AVX512DQ doesn't come "before" or "after" AVX512ER, for example.  You can (in theory) have either, both, or neither.  (In practice, Skylake-X/Cannonlake/etc. has only a bit of overlap with Xeon Phi (Knight's Landing / Knight's Mill), beyond AVX512F.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#CPUs_with_AVX-512

Comment: Confirming your point about popcnt having its own feature bit:  I peeked into MSVC's library implementation of `std::popcount`.  If AVX is defined, it assumes the popcnt intrinsic is available.  If AVX is not defined, it does a runtime check of the architecture for `__ISA_AVAILABLE_SSE442`.  In other words, if you target AVX, the implementation assumes that implies SSE4.2, including popcnt.

Answer (score 3):

If we set compiler option `-mavx2` that GCC doesn't give an error when we use AVX or SSE intrinsics. So GCC supposes that existing of AVX2 flag is enough to run AVX and SSE code. Of course it does not garante that someone won't create CPU with AVX2 and without SSE.

Comment: I guess the question can be rephrased asking if somebody has already made a CPU (commercial) with AVX2 and without SSE.

Comment: @Ruben I think that creation of such CPU has no sense. When I create code with AVX2 (I have been doing this for over 5 years) I of course also use AVX and SSE code and I don't have any troubles.

Comment: Such a CPU would not be commercially viable because it couldn't run real-world existing code.  Except possibly in a Xeon-Phi type of device where it's only ever expected to run code compiled specifically for it.  (But if so, why would you ever pick x86 instead of a cleaner and cheaper-to-license ISA like AArch64 or RISC-V, unless you're Intel...  But anyway, actual Xeon Phi devices *do* support legacy-SSE up to 4.2, and AVX1/2, and MMX / x87 so you can run existing binaries.  The point of my example was an even more special-purpose device.)

Answer (score 1):

In principle, a CPU could just support AVX2 without supporting any SSE4 instructions (Which isn't as stupid an idea as it sounds!). In practice though, if it supports AVX2, it also supports SSE4.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not true.  AVX2 implies AVX, and AVX implies that the VEX encoding of SSE4.2 instructions like `vpcmpistri` are available.  I *think* it also implies that the non-VEX encoding is available, too.  In theory you could make a CPU which didn't accept the non-VEX encoding, but I think you'd be violating Intel's guarantees about what the AVX feature bit implies.  Not sure if that's formally written down in a manual, though.