# Does -mavx2 implies -mavx and -msse4.2

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, clang, avx

From what I understand every CPU that supports AVX2 supports AVX, and every CPU that supports AVX supports SSE4.2.
Does that mean that just specifying `-mavx2` is enough or there is a difference between:

```
-msse4.2 -mavx -mavx2
```

and

```
-mavx2
```

All I found in GCC docs is this(AVX SSE relationship):

> GCC depresses SSEx instructions when -mavx is used. Instead, it generates new AVX instructions or AVX equivalence for all SSEx instructions when needed.

I presume this just means that GCC will use better AVX instructions instead of SSE instructions, so I guess this implies when you have -mavx that msse4.2 is useless, but I could not find anything wrt `-mavx2` `-mavx` relationship.

I also looked up the clang docs, could not find anything.

Note: I am compiling C++ code, but I presume answer is same for C and C++ compilers.

Comment: near duplicate about the actual ISA features, where my answer does mention that GCC `-mavx2` implies all earlier Intel SIMD extensions: [Do all CPUs which support AVX2 also support SSE4.2 and AVX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53443249) (yes).

Comment: @PeterCordes I would leave this question since it may be easier to find, but yes, your answer answers my question.

Comment: Right, duplicates can be useful signposts.  Closing as a duplicate doesn't lead to auto-deletion by the roomba unless the score is negative.  (I'll upvote this in case the threshold is 0 rather than -1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at the active flags for gcc by adding `-Q --help=target` to the command line.

Pipe into files, compare. The two sets of options produced identical settings for me.